# Select value based on other column value with related values

Tags: excel

```
Column1, Column2
x, North
x, South
x, East
x, West

Related Data
North
North City 1
North City 2
South
South City 1
South City 2
etc.
...
```

Trying to solve for x value up above. For example, if the value is North, then pick a random city from the North group only.

Answer (score 0):

If the ranges of the cells for North, South, etc. are fixed, you could try using the Random command with the row numbers of the sections as your arguments. (e.g. RandBetween(10,20) for North)

The RandBetween will return the row of the cell selected at random.
Then use the Index function to return the actual value.

```
=Index("A1:A1000", RandBetween(BeginValue, EndValue), 1)
```